# Why is my button not taking up the blue space to the right of my button?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**There is a blue space next to my support button when I inspect and click on the navbar. Why is it there and *not* taking up the full space. It is supposed to be pushed all the way to the right. I have only used flexbox.**

What I wanted to do was have it take that space and get rid of it.

```css
:root {
  --cta-color: #a82534;
  --main-grey-color: #e2dde1;
  --brown-color: #a08f81;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--main-grey-color);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      left,
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 0.2)
    ),
    url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61fZ%2BYAYGaL._SX569_.jpg")
      no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
      left,
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 0.2)
    ),
    url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61fZ%2BYAYGaL._SX569_.jpg")
      no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 10),
      rgba(226, 221, 225, 0.2)
    ),
    url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61fZ%2BYAYGaL._SX569_.jpg")
      no-repeat;
  /*  background-size: contain;*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
}

/*
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: var(--brown-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1800px;
  width: 89%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "brownregular";
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  width: 86%;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.nav-logo {
  height: 82px;
  width: 80px;
}

.nav1,
.nav2,
.nav3 {
  margin: 5px 40px;
}

.nav3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.ig {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.ig,
.fb {
  height: 25px;
  width: 23px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav4-button {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #a82534;
  width: 8em;
  height: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav4 {
  margin-left: 0 auto;
}
.white-text {
  color: white;
}

.primary-header-container {
  padding-top: 6.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.primary-header {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.sub-header-container {
  padding-top: 2.3em;
}

.sub-header {
  font-size: 1.35rem;
}

.desc {
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
}

.underline {
  border-bottom: solid 10px #73353c;
  width: fit-content;
}

ul,
li,
.desc-link {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #a89da7;
}

.hero-section {
  max-width: 1800px;
  width: 77%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "jelleebold";
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

p {
  font-family: "brownlight";
}

.section-bg-color {
  background-color: #f4f3f4;
  padding: 135px 0px;
}

.card_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1590px;
  width: 78.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  width: 370px;
  /* Set width of cards */
  height: 370px;
  display: flex;
  /* Children use Flexbox */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Rotate Axis */
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Fixes the corners */
}

.card-header {
  color: #d32f2f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;
  /* Children use Flexbox */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Rotate Axis to Vertical */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Group Children in Center */
  align-items: center;
  /* Group Children in Center (on cross axis) */
  padding: 15px 0;
  /* Add padding to the top/bottom */
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #d32f2f;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.main-description {
  color: #d32f2f;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sectioncampaign-bg-color {
  background-color: #e5dfe3;
  padding: 150px 0px;
}

.sectioncampaign-container {
  width: 1392px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-family: "jelleebold";
  color: white;
}

.body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 45px;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
  <main>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img class="nav-logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/HAWAwVg.png" alt="cat laying down logo" /></a> </div>
      <div class="nav-items">
        <div class="nav1"><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></div>
        <div class="nav2"><a href="#">Shop</a></div>
        <div class="nav3"><a href="nav3">Get involved</a></div>
        <div class="social-icons middle">
          <img class="ig" src="https://i.imgur.com/UTO8Ake.png" alt="instagram icon link" />
          <img class="fb" src="https://i.imgur.com/UTO8Ake.png" alt="instagram icon link" />
        </div>
        <a href="nav4.html" class="nav4-button">

          <div class="nav4"><span class="white-text">Support</span> </div>
        </a>

        <!--          <div class="services"><a href="nav3">Services</a></div>-->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  /header -->
  </main>
```

https://codepen.io/ninabor/pen/ExKMqrm

Comment: maybe change the  width:86% to width:100%

Comment: are you saying about the margin on the right ?

Comment: There's really no need to post your code here and then in executable form on a third party site. You can do that, right here, in your question by inserting your code as a Stack Snippet, which I've done for you.

Comment: When I click INSPECT then I click the navbar class it shows a blue space to the right which I thought the button would take up that space.

Comment: I wonder if this is a browser quirk. Which browser are you using. I've just tried Chrome and didnt see a blue space..
https://jsbin.com/pudidojoyo/edit?output

Comment: .nav-items has margin of 20px on left and right

Answer (score 0):

```
     
     max-width: 1800px;
     width: 90%;
     padding-top: 2px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     font-family: "brownregular";
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   
   .nav-items {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     width:100%;
   }
```

I fixed it by adding 100% width to items and 90% to navbar